# Math frac with multiple lines and columns

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible to recreate a multiline and column frac within LaTeX ?

[image]

Comment: Here it is possible to recreate...."all". Have you tried something? Do you want to create a table? For example I have not understood your question. Why do you have ask frac?

Comment: In your case I think it would be better to use a table with no visible lines. Doing this in mathematical mode would not have a good result in visual aesthetics.

Comment: I agree with the others, I'd probably do this as a piece of gfx via tikz.